# Get First Image Result from Google

Tags: web-crawler, google-search, google-search-api, google-crawlers, google-image-search

I'd like to achieve some images for a large database I have. Instead of searching, downloading and renaming one by one, I thinked about a script that would return, for every key, the first **google images** result downloaded into my server.

Is this possible? Something about web crawlers? I've searched through Google API documentation and other StackOverflow posts but none answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to download all of the images on each keyword.
even if it's possible it is very hard to do.
The images link to other webpages and no script can do such a thing.